# Definition of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying the inner product part in linear algebra and it's a bit tricky to understand what inner product really means. It indicates the length of vectors? So if we calculate $<x,y>$ we have to make it as a scalar?
Here is an example. If $x$ and $y$ are column vector of $2*2$ matrix and $F=R$ then we calculate $\langle x,y\rangle=x^T y$. I wonder it is equivalent to $x^T y=y^T x$ (because it results in the same value)? Seriously, there is no difference?
Also, the example says if $x$ and $y$ are  column vector of $2*2$ matrix and $F=R$ then $\langle x,y\rangle=y^* x$ where $*$ means conjugate transpose. I can't understand why...

Comment: Tip: write the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle$ as `$\langle x,y\rangle$` it looks better.

Comment: Inner products are more related to angles. Or how much orthogonal are two vectors.

Comment: Dou you mean Inner product as Dot product?

Comment: Right. Dot product!

Comment: Matt explained it quite well, just want to stress that *unlike the cross porduct), the dot product is just a plain number, unitless, not a vector. FYI, when the dot product attains zero, the vectors are said to be orthogonal, did you know that?

Comment: You can view my explanation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362123/simple-dot-product-question/362155#362155) or in the Wikipedia for a more general understanding of the term "inner product".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner (or dot) product of two real-valued vectors is defined by
$$\sum_ix_iy_i$$
where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the components of the two vectors. This is why $x^Ty=y^Tx$. If the vectors are complex-valued the inner product is defined by
$$\sum_ix_iy_i^{*}$$
This results in $x^{*}x=||x||^2$ (real-valued norm), which is what you want, also for complex vectors.

Comment: Isn't it $x_i \bar{y_i}$ in sigma? (bar means conjugation) Since it becomes $y^* x$ and $*$ means conjugate transpose.

Comment: I agree that this is "the" dot product. But calling it "the" inner product is a misuse, as there is a general concept of "an" inner product, which can be different.

Comment: @noname: I used * for conjugate transpose, which in the scalar case means simply conjugate. It's the same as using a bar. Choose whichever you prefer.

Comment: @MattL. This is a specific "inner product" AKA dot product AKA standard inner product AKA common inner product but not "the" inner product so I'd agree with Tobias...

Comment: @Scis: Of course I agree with you and Tobias. What I meant was "the" inner product that the OP was talking about.